# how to stop strip html tags JOOMLA 1.5 when saving

Tags: joomla1.5

I have in my form text box name="html" (test`<font color="red">testcolor</font>`)

when i later use with my `save()` function

```
$row=&JTable::getInstance('something','Table')
$row->bind($post)
$row->store()
```

result inDB is `test`

How can i stop stripping HTML tags?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `serialize` or `base64_encode` for encoding the data and save them.

When retrieving the data you need to `unserialize` or `bash64_decode` to decode the data to use.

Comment: and where can i have use it? $post['html']->base64_encode[$post['html']

Comment: $post['html'] = base64_encode[$post['html']; just before binding $post